# Erro em leitura de arquivo em C++

Tags: c++

Alguém sabe me dizer porque a saída desse programa está sendo apenas "end"? O arquivo naocompre.txt está no mesmo diretório do programa.

Segue o código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


int main ()
{
string info;
ifstream input("naocompre.txt");
if(input.is_open()) {
    while(!input.eof()) {
           string info;
           getline(input,info);
           cout<<info<<endl;
    }
}
    cout<<"end"<<"\n";
    return 0;

}
```

Conteúdo de naocompre.txt:

```
NaoCompre Costeira 
5 
7 
4 
Maria_Benta 1 800 
Juliana_Digito 1 800 
Zeca_Mole 3 180 
Joao_DeMora 3 180
```

Comment: Precisaria *debugar*. Ver onde ele está executando, onde está pulando, ir isolando o problema até chegar no ponto que indique o problema. Ele pode não ter conseguido abrir o arquivo, ou pode ser alguma coisa com os dados. Exceto por não estar fechando o arquivo, o que não é um problema em algo tão simples, não estou vendo problemas no código. Pode ter me escapado.

Comment: O código não entra no `if(input.is_open()) { ... }` ou seja, o arquivo não foi encontrado ou não pode ser aberto (ele não está aberto em outro programa?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O programa está correto. O problema é no seu ambiente. Como comentado por @stderr, ou o arquivo não existe, ou está em outro diretório, ou tem outro nome, ou alguma coisa do tipo.

PS. "Na minha máquina funcionou."

Comment: Realmente, compilando pelo terminal fora do eclipse funciona normalmente, mas por que será que no Eclipse não funciona?

Comment: Resolvido. Para executar no eclipse era necessário especificar o caminho completo do arquivo.